# DNS propagation not happening on local network

Tags: networking, dns, nameserver

I've read lots of similar questions and answers but nothing fits.

I updated my website's nameserver to reflect a change with my hosting company.  Did this on Friday or Saturday with my registrar (different than host).

Per Whois, the nameserver change was nearly instantaneous.  However, as of Wednesday morning (96 to 120 hours later), I still can't connect on my network.  Part of the trouble might be that the IP hasn't changed - only the tld of the nameserver.

I can connect on different networks, and I can connect from an anonymizing proxy, but not from devices on my LAN.

Steps I've taken:

1. Flushed DNS cache
2. Released and renewed with IPConfig
3. Re-registered DNS
4. Switched to Google DNS
5. Switched to static IP
6. Reset my router
7. Rebooted my PC
8. Flushed my ARP Cache
9. Changed the ipAdress for the old webhost  to the new web host in my `hosts` file.

When I type `nslookup -d mysite.com`, the output still shows the old name server.

If this is with my ISP, I'd expect that switching to Google DNS would've covered it.  What could be happening here?